# Knockout JS observables, removing and re-adding select options

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So I am familiar with knockout observables but this issue is a bit tricky.

So assume you have some data: `var data = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird']`

Now lets assume you have two drop downs that use this data, so both are populated with same data.

If I select cat in drop down A, then I should not see cat in Drop down B. It should be removed. How ever if I then select bird in drown down A, it should then be removed from drop down B and cat should be re-added as a select option. The same should be said if I select cat from drop down B, it should be removed from A.

Now where have I gotten? No where other then:

```
viewModel.dropDownA.subscribe(function(selectedValueFromB){ });
viewModel.dropDownB.subscribe(function(selectedValueFromA){ });
```

I am not even sure if I set these up properly, like how would I make drop down B listen to what is going on in drop down A and vice versa?

**Help**

Comment: Do you need to do this with an unknown number of dropdowns or is it always just the two?

Comment: @JasonSpake It's always two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're dealing with a small number of dropdowns you can do this pretty easily with computed functions.

Html:

```
<select data-bind="options: optionsA, optionsCaption: '', value: selectedA"></select>
<select data-bind="options: optionsB, optionsCaption: '', value: selectedB"></select>
```

JS:

```
    var self = this;

    self.data = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird'];
    self.selectedA = ko.observable();
    self.selectedB = ko.observable();

    self.optionsA = ko.computed(function(){
      return self.data.filter(function(item){
        return item !== self.selectedB();
      });
    });

    self.optionsB = ko.computed(function(){
      return self.data.filter(function(item){
        return item !== self.selectedA();
      });
    });
```